# fluxgui / python-gconf not installable on Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, f.lux

On Kubuntu 19.04 I'm trying to install f.lux, but I'm missing python-gconf dependency. When I try to install it, the terminal says:

```
Package python-gconf is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source 
E: Package 'python-gconf' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install `python-gconf` manually from [*cosmic* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/python-gconf):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python/python-gconf_2.28.1+dfsg-1.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gconf_2.28.1+dfsg-1.2_amd64.deb
```

(usually this method is not recommended, but we do not have other methods)